# How to set table width based on cell widths specified in percentages?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table inside a `div` who has a `width` of `100%` which is inside another `div` with again a width of `100%` but also a `max-width` of `816px`.
I don't have a width for my table but it gets its width from its cells whose widths I have in pixels (`121px` and `108px`, its a two column table). So far so good, but now I am trying make my table responsive and for that I need to mention my cell widths in percentages.

This is where the trouble comes in, the `width` of my cells in %ages is `14%` and `13%` respectively. The calculation is with respect to the outermost `div` which has a `max-width` of `816px`. Now what is happening is, since the table doesn't has a `width` it gets expanded to the whole width of the `div`.

Is there a solution to this problem without specifying any `width` to the table in pixels (table `width` in percentages is OK)?

Comment: How wide do you want the table to be when the window is narrower? When the div is at its maximum, the table can be 28% wide, obviously (and the cells can be 52% and 48% wide) but what if there's less space? Can the table shrink proportionally?

Comment: yes the table should shrink proportionally when the window shrinks which is happening but the trouble is, in the full sized window the table stretches to the whole width of the containing `div` and consequently the table cells are also stretched.

Comment: In that case I may misunderstand your requirements. I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3sMgN/) that shows it works as in my first comment. So if that doesn't work for you, your environment is different.